# Ajax in Struts2

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am new to Struts and Ajax. I tried to develop a page like Gmail. In Gmail we enter user name and we click next to type password. I tried dojo plugins,Jquery and Jason jars. Didn't get the desired result. So please advice me on what to use and whether I should choose  different Frame Work.

Comment: too broad, post some of your code and where you are having problems, to get started

Comment: also note that struts2 is kind of old framework (although quite thorough), search around for newer frameworks, like play or spring (if you need too much stuff)

Comment: @NikosM.: **S2 is not old.**

Answer (score 2):

**Which MVC?**

Struts2 is widely accepted MVC framework which you can use to develop web based applications. There are more alternatives, like spring, and each comes with advantages and disadvantages. You can add ajax to your web application regardless of which MVC you choose to use.

**AJAX in general**

What Ajax does is to simply query your application (that is to call a specific function you define) but without refreshing the whole page. So you can update parts of your web page with loading everything which is quite useful.

**Struts2 and Ajax**

There are some alternatives on how to configure struts with ajax which you can find in struts' website. The quickest way to get started is to write a jquery ajax call to one of your functions of your action class (I assume you are familiar with the MVC concepts). This can be done like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: dataType
}).done(function (){ ...
    });
```

The important part here is the url which has to point to the function you want to call. You need to check your xml action configuration and function name to figure out your url. If your action is named actionA and your function has name functionName then the url will be like:
"actionA.functionName.action".

So your action class will be looking like this:

```
public class action{
...
    public String methodName(){
        ...
        return "actionName";
    }
...
}
```

and your action configuration like this:

```
<action name="actionName" class="Your Action Class">
    <result name="done">yourPage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When your ajax call is done a result is returned which is the result of the method you call. In the example above this will be html code as described in yourPage.jsp. The important thing here is that the html code returned will contain results of the method you called. In order to present these results in your page you cna of course parse resulting html and for this you may use jQuery.

**Struts2 with Json support**

Struts of course supports Json. That means you can return a Json response which as you can imagine is a lot better than plain html responses. To do this you need to have the "json plugin" available for your project. If you are using maven you need to include the dependencies in your pom.xml

https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html

The thing that change is that your jquery must be a json request. You can do that either by changing 'POST' to 'Json' in the $.ajax call shown above, or use $.getJSON(url,function) which is the same thing.

However your action configuration must be updated to sth like

```
<action name="dataTablesAction" class="your action class">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="noCache">true</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use struts 2 jquery plugin (show case at http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) This plugin integrated lots of jquery features and components with struts2. It will save you lots of jQuery coding!

For example for doing ajax you will get two tags `sj:a` and `sj:submit` which sends a form to server, valdiate the result and return proper result, without you need to write a single jQuery js

Comment: I would say the plugin is a great starting point for newcomers to AJAX usage with Struts, but any type of complicated and heavily UI intensive view will still require a fair amount of custom jQuery coding to glue it all together, despite the plugin's use.

Comment: @Naros of course it depends on the project UI which you work on. We used it in one of our project and it was a life saver. We found the publish/subscribe plugin/concept, which is supported by all `sj` tags,  a great place which you can extend and add your custom UI requirement.